# Can I assign an array value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to assign an array value to a variable. It always returns undefined.

In my code I have set currentWord = text[wordPos]. At the end of the code I have console logged currentWord, and text[wordPos]. My thinking says that they should return the same value, but they don't. currentWord returns undefined, and text[wordPos] returns the correct value (the first word in the 'text' array).

**Solved. I had mistakenly forgot that I had 2 arrays, and thought the text array was not empty, but it was. The words array is the array I had filled in separate file.**

```js
var text = Array();

var wordPos = 0;
var currentWord = text[wordPos];

function gen() {
  text = [];
  var random;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)];
    text.push(random);
  }
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text.join(" ");

  console.log(currentWord);
  console.log(text[wordPos]);
}
```

Comment: new Array results in an empty array ... text[0] is undefined ... therefore currentWord is undefined (one of the 5 (6 in ES2015+) primitive types in javascript)... changing currentWord wont change the array ... changing the array wont change currentWord - assigning  primitive types assigns by value, not by reference

Comment: Look at the first 3 lines: you initialize an array (which is now empty) and you try to access index zero... Why would you expect anything other than `undefined` at this point?

Comment: I may not have made it clear that the array is contained in a separate file. I'm only declaring it here.

Comment: @GarrettSmith - makes no difference .. primitive types assign by value not by reference ... `undefined` is a primitive

Comment: I'm sorry, still a bit confused on why console.log(text[wordPos]); gives me the result I want then.

Comment: Scratch that. I have found the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currentwork is undefined because you create an array object but never push a value into it. It transfers the current value of the variable not the reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value at index 0 of text. If you assign some values to the text array you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

Read the OP's note above about the two arrays in the original example. In light of this information, the following script simulates an imported array **words** of 50 distinct values in order to generate a text of ten space-delimited numbers and indicate its first value:

```js
// simulating an array imported from a separate file
  var words = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50];
  
  
  function gen() {
  var wordPos = 0; 
  var currentWord = "";

  var arr = [];
  var randomVal;
  var d = document;
  d.g = d.getElementById;
  var pText = d.g('text');
  
  // get each of 10 values by randomly selecting an element's key
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomVal = words[ Math.floor( Math.random() * 50 ) ];
    arr.push( randomVal );
   }
  
  pText.innerHTML = arr.join(" ");
  currentWord = arr[wordPos]; 
  console.log("Current word: ",currentWord );
}

gen();
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

This script randomly selects 10 numbers and adds them to an empty array by means of variable **randomVal**.  This variable acquires a value in each iteration of the for-loop, during which the variable is passed to the  push() method of **arr** in order to append it to the array.  Once the loop terminates, the script [joins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements of **arr** on a blank space character, which yields a string whose numeric values are space-delimited.

One can discern that the script is working correctly when the console.log statement displays the first numeric value appearing in the text.